# Is 'dropwhile' static? can I make it dynamic?

Tags: python, python-itertools

**Introduction**

I came up with a cunning solution to my problem but, not-so-cunning, it doesn't work :-/

After hours of clicking through the debugger I *think*, so perhaps you can verify this, that the reason it doesn't work is because `itertools.dropwhile`, after the initial declaration, is fixed - whereas I was hoping I could alter the input parameters to the predicate on every loop.

The task below attempts to pick a startdate, then an enddate that follows it, then a startdate that follows that, and an enddate after the last... and so on, so that we end up with a series of date intervals which don't overlap. The startdates come from one list, and the enddates from another.

The following solution loops over the startdates, then over the enddates, using `dropwhile` to pass over the dates which are in '*the past*'. It works perfectly on the first time through. But on the second pass the enddate gets stuck at '2009-12-14'. I broke out "isbefore" routine just so I could see when it gets tested, and when it doesn't.  Not sure, but I think what is happening is that the whole `dropwhile` test gets set in stone on the first pass, and doesn't recompile itself on each pass? Like I'd hoped/expected.

To finish it off I was hoping to wrap it all inside a `while True` and exit via a `StopIteration` exception, thus extracting the full sequence of intervals. But it never fires. When I tried neither iterator would actually 'next' all the way to its end.

**Questions**

1. Is that (the set-in-stone conclusion) correct as to what's happening?
2. Is there an short, clean, elegant way to make it behave the way I'd hoped? Do I have to write my own dropwhile which acts the way I want?

**Code**

```
import itertools
import datetime

startdates = [
    datetime.date(2009, 11, 5), datetime.date(2009, 11, 13),
    datetime.date(2009, 12, 4), datetime.date(2009, 12, 7),
    datetime.date(2009, 12, 29), datetime.date(2009, 12, 30)]

enddates = [
    datetime.date(2009, 10, 1), datetime.date(2009, 10, 2),
    datetime.date(2009, 11, 4), datetime.date(2009, 12, 14),
    datetime.date(2009, 12, 15),datetime.date(2009, 12, 30)]

enddate = datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)
startdate = datetime.date(1900, 1, 1)

def isbefore(a, b):
    return a <= b

for startdate in itertools.dropwhile(lambda date: isbefore(date, enddate), startdates):
    for enddate in itertools.dropwhile(lambda date: isbefore(date, startdate), enddates):
        print startdate, enddate
        break
```

**Current Output**

```
2009-11-05 2009-12-14
2009-11-13 2009-12-14
2009-12-04 2009-12-14
2009-12-07 2009-12-14
```

**Desired Output**

```
2009-11-05 2009-12-14
2009-12-29 2009-12-30
```

The more observant types will notice I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102751) yesterday which presents the same problem, but that one calls for a general solution whereas this time I'm asking specifically about the workings of dropwhile.

Comment: It's always immediately after you post you realize something important: Maybe its the for..in loop that gets fixed - I'm trying to change the iterator on it after its started!?

Comment: I hope I am not stating the obvious, but you reuse `startdate` and `enddate` in a way that is confusing, no? I also get different output than you do.

Comment: Obviously the startdate and enddate are changing all the time. Does that pose a problem? for the lambda? Can I detach those issues by feeding them into a routine like isbefore?  I couldn't see how to create a predicate for dropwhile that consumes the value without using lambda?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once `dropwhile` has dropped the items which satisfy the predicate, it yields the rest of the iterable unmodified. Using `itertools.ifilterfalse` in its place gives your desired output, as it will continue to process the predicate even after the initial run.

Comment: Or he could simply use a genexp.

Comment: In this example I was actually able to find a solution which didn't need itertools (or genexp) at all; but this works, got me there, and answered the question. Tick.